# How can I leave empty values in gmap field?

Tags: google-maps

I use gmap module to display a map on nodes that I want to have a location. On some nodes I don't want any location, and on those I don't want the map displayed at all. I tried to set default value in lat/long-fields to NaN or leave them empty, but then I get error when I save the node. Is there any way I can choose to display the map or not?

Comment: You want to omit some values, or field altogether?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an option to leave field blank, simply don't make it required. Go to */admin/structure/types/manage/your_content_type/fields/field_name* and clear the "required" checkbox.

[image: screenshot of checkbox mentioned above]

Comment: The field is not required. But I can not leave lat/long fields empty.

Comment: @tofu in that case you found a bug and you should be posting in module's issue queue, not here.